# ArcMap 10.5: Point layer's custom symbols not all exporting with geoprocessing

Tags: arcgis-server, symbology, file-geodatabase, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-10.5

I am using a Geoprocessing Service to export (package and send email to download) an mxd with it's sourced file geodatabase. One of the point layers in my mxd has custom symbols. Once I export my files and download the mxd with it's gdb, sometimes my point layer has all the custom symbols, and sometimes it only has a few. The features of my layer do exist after I download, but the custom symbols which are images are lost.

Is there a specific way to save the custom symbol images, so they are not lost upon exporting or is there any reason why the symbol images would be lost while being processed with the Geoprocessing service?

Comment: What GP function are you using? Have you tried creating a map package?

Comment: @BenSNadler Using the map package did work but I found the initial problem was just the version of my .mxd. I was saving it in 10.5 when it was supposed to be saved as 10.0. :p

Answer (score 1):

I found the initial problem was just the version of my .mxd. I was saving it in 10.5 when it was supposed to be saved as 10.0. So I did this and it solved my problem!